# JavaScript Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried to run below code but chrome showed **Unexpected token ILLEGAL** .
Can anyone help ?

When I click the button, it should add the  tag, and when it find **images/1h.jpg** it does not exist ,it should trigger **onerror**event and run **function onc()** to add some CSS and load another picture, but it didnt run **function onc()** and when I access console ,it shows **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL** .

```html
<button id='a' onclick="onc();">aaa</button>
<div></div>
```

```js
function onc(){
 var path1= 'images/1h.jpg';//Does not exist
 var path2= 'images/1s.jpg';//exist
 var tmp = "<img src='"+path1+"' onerror='nofind(this,"+path2+");' /> ";
 $('div').html(tmp);
}
```

I searched some answers, it seems caused by  "" or '', but I really don't know how to fix my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the rendered JavaScript in the HTML attribute text, the string you have in `path2` won't be in quotes, it'll look like this:

```
onerror='nofind(this,images/1s.jpg);'
```

One solution is to put it in quotes:

```
var tmp = "<img src='"+path1+"' onerror='nofind(this,\""+path2+"\");' /> ";
// Change is here -----------------------------------^^---------^^
```

...which renders like this:

```
onerror='nofind(this,"images/1s.jpg");'
```

A better solution, though, would be not to use an `onXyz` attribute at all. There's no reason to. Instead, use modern event handling:

```
function onc(){
    var path1= 'images/1h.jpg';//Does not exist
    var path2= 'images/1s.jpg';//exist
    var img = $("img").on("error", function() {
                  nofind(this, path2);
              }).attr("src", path1);
    $('div').html(img);
}
```

Note that we hook the `error` event **before** setting the `src` attribute. This may not be strictly necessary with `error` depending on the reason for the error, but it's a good habit to get into and it can matter quite a lot for the related `load` event. (It's a common misconception that you can hook the `load` event after setting `src`; it works *most* of the time, but may not if the browser has the image cached and the cache settings for it allow the browser to reuse it without revalidating it, in which case the browser may fire the `load` event as soon as `src` is set and, not seeing any JavaScript handlers, doesn't queue them to run when the JavaScript thread is next free to run handlers. [There is only one main JavaScript UI thread, but *browsers* are multi-threaded.])

Comment: really thanks T.J! it works. it puzzled me so long time. You are so cool!

Comment: @leo: :-) No worries.